# Advanced Custom Fields: Image Crop Add-on plugin doing nothing for me in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields, resize-crop

I am using Wordpress 4.6.1 version. 
first time, I install the plugin and activate it.
second time, I copied plugin folder into my theme and paste this code into functions.php

```
add_action('acf/register_fields', 'my_register_fields');

function my_register_fields()
{
    include_once('acf-image-crop/acf-image-crop.php');
}
```

But both time i don't see any options like this
[enter link description here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-image-crop-add-on/screenshots/)

I also R&D on this but get nothing.
please someone guide. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you've tried the following steps:

1. Downloaded ACF plugin and add it to your site, activated it.
2. Downloaded the ACF Image crop plugin and moved it into your theme folder
3. Added the specified code to your functions to register the acf image crop

If you've tried all of the above, try adjusting the acf-image-crop code to the following:

```
add_action('acf/register_fields', 'my_register_fields');

function my_register_fields()
{
    include_once(get_template_directory_uri() . 'acf-image-crop/acf-image-crop.php');
}
```

Comment: u mean to say firstly I activated the plugin and then paste in themes??

Comment: Firstly activate ACF, then include the ACF crop in your theme folder. They are two separate entities and you'll require both to get this to work.